# Can Kensai Improve a Soulbow's weapon?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, multi-classing, psionics, class

I am preparing to DM a D&D 3.5e game. One of my players is trying to go Soulbow into Kensai. Can Kensai actually enhance the Soulbow's weapon? I am not sure if it can do that, as it is just an arrow that gets shot into enemies and dissipates.

Answer (score 2):

Kensai and soulbow are both rather weak classes. The interaction is, officially, rather dubious (kensai has you choose a specific, individual weapon, not a kind of weapon, and each mind arrow is described as separate, freshly-manifested weapon, separate from any prior), but that isn’t a good enough reason, in my opinion, to rule against this player. Their PC will most likely need all the help they can get.